# how to escape the single quotes when use sshpass

Tags: linux, shell, escaping, single-quotes

ssh remote over gateway

`sshpass -p gatewaypwd -t user@gateway sshpass -p targetpwd ssh user2@target`
this is the origin command,and i am put it to my alias. it run well.
but now the target host's password contains single quotes
 such as

`sshpass -p gatewaypwd -t user@gateway sshpass -p target'pwd ssh user2@target`
the command can not run well. 
i did try to escape it by `\'` ,`\\\'` and other method ,but neither success. 
how to escape the quotes.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

1. Store your password in text file
2. Use `sshpass -f <filename> ssh user@IP_ADDR`

It will take password from file. I have tried this with blank space and it works fine.

Comment: This worked for me, since the password I was using had both single and double quotes in it.

Answer (score 1):

Use double-quotes around the password.

Comment: Much better solution than storing the password in a text file